# AttachDBFileName is not working after deployment

Tags: c#, sql-server-express

I have defined connection string in my app.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StoreConnectionString"
    connectionString="Data Source=(local);MultipleActiveResultSets=True;AttachDBFileName=C:\Users\Firdavs\Desktop\Data\StoreServer.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  
  </connectionStrings>
```

I am using c# and sql express in my application. When I am running in Visual Studio in my machine it works fine.  But after creating setup and deploying into other machine. I am editing .exe.config file showing AttachDBFileName=Path. Application is giving me error. Sql Express is installed in that machine. I guess attaching is not working. What do you advice?
Please show me direction!

Answer (score 2):

the problem is here : "AttachDBFileName=C:\Users\Firdavs\Desktop\Data\StoreServer.mdf;"

when you deploy it to another machine, that absolute path has low changes to be the same...you need to give a virtual path...

you need to copy the mdf in the same directory. Then in visual studio make sure that when you select the mdf file , you change the property of "Copy to Output Directory" to be "Copy if newer" (you change it by double-clicking on the "do not copy" text already listed there)
  and then change AttachDbFilename to be ...  AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|StoreServer.mdf;....

Comment: How to give virtual path? Can you please give me more information with example?

Comment: check out the new info i gave you above

Comment: What is |DataDirectory| in c# application?

Answer (score 0):

As I've said before on this site - the whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! Visual Studio will be copying around the `.mdf` file and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `StoreServer`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=(local);Database=StoreServer;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

When you deploy to a customer's PC - go through the same steps: install SQL Server Express, create the database **on the server**, connect to it using the `server=(local)` (or the `server=machinename` approach) - and be done with it!

Comment: Thank you marc_s for your answer. But I do not want to install sql server management studio in my clients machine. I just want to make my application easy to install with one package. I just want my clients setup the application and start working. As my setup project allows to setup sql express if it is not installed. But when attaching DBFileName I have this issue. If I install SQL Server Management studio they can see my database structure. It is not good.

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov: if you want to, you can do all this **without** Mgmt Studio - just use `sqlcmd` from the command line

Comment: Is there other way doing it automatically?

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov: you could program out everything in C# using the SMO (SQL Server Management Objects) library

Comment: Any example will be appreciated or any link where it is told. Thanks.

Comment: Just Google! You'll find e.g. [Using SMO for Backup, Restore and Security Purposes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14848/Using-SMO-for-Backup-Restore-and-Security-Purposes), [Getting Started with SMO in SQL 2005](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=34), [Backup and Restore SQL Server databases programmatically with SMO](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1849/backup-and-restore-sql-server-databases-programmatically-with-smo/) and **a lot more** ....